# how to name templates for same content types

Tags: theming, 8

I have a Content Type machine name as `"aktionsblock_oben"` and made some content and get the Content ID as 33 for this one. Now I can use template name as `page--node--33.html.twig`, but what if I create new content like this where I get another ID? The `page--node--33.html.twig` won't fire.

My try `page--node--aktionsblock_oben.html.twig` or `aktionsblock_oben.html.twig` was a failure.

Any suggestions

Comment: You need a theme suggestion, see the linked answer. And replace the underscore to hyphen in `aktionsblock-oben`

Answer (score 0):

By default [page.html.twig](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions) won't work content type specific pages, you'll have to assign a template file name manually. Check the example below which [create a new template name for content type](https://www.drupal.org/node/2521876#comment-10684366):

```
function [THEME_NAME]_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Add content type suggestions.
  if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {
    array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'page__node__' . $node->getType());
  }
}
```

With help of above code, you can use `page--node--aktionsblock_oben.html.twig` template file as your content type template file.